# New MacBook Pro M1 keep asking for admin password

Tags: xcode, administrator, serveradmin

Keep asking, and does not accept password, though it is the right password

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is to small to read the text on the dialog, can you add a bigger version? Also: What triggers the dialog?

Comment: You're doing something in Xcode. Does it happen in other apps? What are you doing when it asks?

Comment: Only in Xcode. I start to build an app for device. It asks for permission to make changes on Keychain Access app.

Comment: @nohillside - I don't think the issue is it being too small to read, more being a tad too Hungarian ;)) [certainly for my poor grasp of it.]

Comment: @tetsujin That makes it even worse...

Comment: Possibly something to do with the certificate used for code-signing, then?

Answer (score -2):

Dude, I had the same problem. I typed the password, I swear, like 200 times. Then it worked. I think it's clearly a bug, but there is an end. You can see that is working because every time (or every 20 times :D) that you type the password, the build in the background is progressing.

Really pretty annoying, but I tried every tricks that I know and this is the only way I made it work.

EDIT:
I fixed by changing the permission to the user private key in the keychain that Xcode was asking the permission (in my case the System Keychain)